# pytables appending recarray

Tags: python

I have stock tick data in csv files and for the life of me I cannot figure out why bulk inserts are not working.  I have created recarray called insert_records with the following types:

```
  [('id', 'O'), ('dt', '<i8'), ('adj_dt', '<i8'), ('currency', 'O'), ('close', '<f8'), ('open', '<f8'), ('high', '<f8'), ('low', '<f8'), ('volume', '<f8')]
```

I have created a table with columns:

```
OHLCTableDescription = {'id': tables.StringCol(10),
                       'dt': tables.Int64Col(),
                       'adj_dt': tables.Int64Col(),
                       'currency': tables.StringCol(5),
                       'open': tables.Float64Col(dflt=np.NaN),
                       'high': tables.Float64Col(dflt=np.NaN),
                       'low': tables.Float64Col(dflt=np.NaN),
                       'close': tables.Float64Col(dflt=np.NaN),
                       "volume": tables.Float64Col(dflt=np.NaN)}
```

*this works:*

```
 for row in insert_records:
     current_row = table.row
     dtype = insert_records.dtype.names
     for j in range(len(dtype)):
         current_row[dtype[j]] = row[j]
         current_row.append()
```

this does not:

```
table.append(insert_records)
```

I get this error

```
 ValueError("rows parameter cannot be converted into a recarray object compliant with table '/TD/date_20130102 (Table(0,), shuffle, zlib(9)) '20130102''. The error was: <Cannot change data-type for object array.>",)
rows parameter cannot be converted into a recarray object compliant with table '/TD/date_20130102 (Table(0,), shuffle, zlib(9)) '20130102''. The error was: <Cannot change data-type for object array.>
```

What does this error refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python objects cannot be used to append to pytables. pytables needs exact recarray datatypes.

This would append if the dtype is changed.

```
 dtype[0] = "|S14"
```