# PyTables ValueError on string column with newer pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, hdf5, pytables

Problem writing pandas dataframe (timeseries) to HDF5 using pytables/tstables:

```
import pandas
import tables
import tstables

# example dataframe
valfloat = [512.3, 918.8]
valstr = ['abc','cba']
tstamp = [1445464064, 1445464013]
df = pandas.DataFrame(data = zip(valfloat, valstr, tstamp), columns = ['colfloat', 'colstr', 'timestamp'])

df.set_index(pandas.to_datetime(df['timestamp'].astype(int), unit='s'), inplace=True)
df.index = df.index.tz_localize('UTC')

colsel = ['colfloat', 'colstr']
dftoadd = df[colsel].sort_index()

# try string conversion from object-type (no type mixing here ?)
##dftoadd.loc[:,'colstr'] = dftoadd['colstr'].map(str)

h5fname = 'df.h5'
# class to use as tstable description
class TsExample(tables.IsDescription):
    timestamp = tables.Int64Col(pos=0)
    colfloat = tables.Float64Col(pos=1)
    colstr = tables.StringCol(itemsize=8, pos=2)
# create new time series
h5f = tables.open_file(h5fname, 'a')
ts = h5f.create_ts('/','example',TsExample)

# append to HDF5
ts.append(dftoadd, convert_strings=True)

# save data and close file
h5f.flush()
h5f.close()
```

Exception:

> ValueError: rows parameter cannot be converted into a recarray object
>   compliant with table `tstables.tstable.TsTable` instance at ...
>   The error was: `cannot view Object as non-Object type`

While this particular error happens with TsTables, the code chunk responsible for it is identical to PyTables [try-section here](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/blob/8bb11b2884b7535e589ce13e809e46aa7c3a8c76/tables/table.py#L2212).

The error is happening after I **upgraded pandas** to `0.17.0`; the same code was running error-free with `0.16.2`.

**NOTE:** if a string column is excluded then everything works fine, so this problem must be related to string-column type representation in the dataframe.

The issue could be related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847587/pytables-appending-recarray). Is there some conversion required for `'colstr'` column of the dataframe that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work with a newer pandas as the index is timezone aware, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0170-tz)

You can:

- convert to a type PyTables understands, this would require localizing
- use HDFStore to write the frame

Note that what you are doing is the reason HDFStore exists in the first place, to make reading/writing pyTables friendly for pandas objects. Doing this 'manually' is full of pitfalls.

Comment: I first thought the problem was in tz-enhanced index, but then why does everything work without the string column (i.e. with the same tz-aware index but only numeric columns in the dataframe)?